# Cobbler+Kickstart $basearch problems

Tags: centos, kickstart, cobbler

I'm using CentOS 6.5 with Cobbler 2.4 (from EPEL). I'm trying to use a heredoc comment to create a repo file (which works) without the `$basearch` being interpreted. What happens is the file is created except `$basearch` is replaced with nothing (e.g. it's removed).

What I have:

```
%post
#raw
cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/blah.repo <<REPO
[repo]
name=repo
baseurl=http://repo.local/repo/$basearch
enabled=1
priority=99
gpgcheck=0
REPO
#end raw
%end
```

What actually gets put in `/etc/yum.repos.d/blah.repo` (`$basearch` is missing):

```
[repo]
name=repo
baseurl=http://repo.local/repo/
enabled=1
priority=99
gpgcheck=0
```

Things I have have verified:

- I know it's not Cobbler or Cheetah because `cobbler validateks` and `cobbler profile getks ...` reports back to me the kickstart script unmodified (when using `#raw` and `#end raw`.
- I created a sample of the template within Cheetah and it properly showed the un-escaped string.

I was doing some further research and found [this](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Changes#Kickstart_Changes_2), from the first bullet it looks like `$basearch` is a special variable within kickstart. Are there any suggestions on how to get around this without using `curl` to get the file or explicitly defining the architecture? I want to keep this within the kickstart file for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had to escape the `#raw` and `#end raw` as it was being interpreted by bash.

```
%post
#raw
cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/blah.repo <<REPO
[repo]
name=repo
baseurl=http://repo.local/repo/\$basearch
enabled=1
priority=99
gpgcheck=0
REPO
#end raw
%end
```